# Changing VS code style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio

I am a beginner.

How can I change my VS code style from this

[image]

to this?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this extension to your VS Code:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons